# SQL Server: Using CTE row results as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server. I have the following issue: I'm creating a CTE based on a start/end date which generates a set of rows for every week between the two dates like this:

```
StartDate       EndDate
2013-02-25 00:00:00.000 2013-03-03 00:00:00.000
2013-04-01 00:00:00.000 2013-04-07 00:00:00.000
```

Now I would like to use the week rows in another SQL statement as columns, so
COLUMN1 | WEEK 1 | WEEK 2 | WEEK 3...

I'm not sure how to accomplish that. My CTE statement is below.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
declare @sDate datetime,
        @eDate datetime

select  @sDate = '2013-02-25',
        @eDate = '2013-04-25';

WITH Weeks_CTE (StartDate, EndDate)
AS
(
  select @sDate StartDate, DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @sDate), 6) EndDate
  union all
  select dateadd(ww, 1, StartDate),
    dateadd(ww, 1, EndDate)
  from Weeks_CTE
  where dateadd(ww, 1, StartDate)<=  @eDate
)
```

Comment: it is not clear from your question, what you want to return. Can you post sample data and results expected.

Comment: As a side note, it best to [not use `BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamp types, especially in SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)  You're not using the statement here, but you may be getting some of the same effect, given that last line: `where dateadd(ww, 1, StartDate)<=  @eDate`.  Also, I'm suspicious about you doing things by _week_, when you're adding **6** days....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to shift row results into columns, you need to do a pivot.

If the columns will be dynamic, based on the results of the first query, you need to do a dynamic pivot.

Please check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query) and do some intense googling to learn about dynamic pivots.